# Can torque angle of motor be positive?

Tags: induction-motor, electromagnetic, electric-machine

For any motor text say that, the rotor field follows the stator field with a certain torque angle. And in case of generator, the stator field follows the rotor field with a negative load angle. The underlying principle is that one field is attracted to another, say in motor the lagging rotor field is attracted to stator field. But why cant the motor action be driven by field repulsion rather than field attraction. For example in motor action, why cant rotor field be leading stator field and be repelled by it to cause motion? This in theory would still cause rotation.

Comment: How would you prevent the rotor from advancing in position (due to repulsion) to the point where it sits somewhere (and not very well defined) between successive stator poles? Then, when a sudden load is placed on the motor, how would you stop it aligning with the more optimum position when magnetic fields are attracting? How would you drive the motor to begin with (from standstill) and avoid the "attractive" position?

Comment: @Andy aka. In a rotating field, the stator field would catch up and push the rotor further. So far I  am hearing about stator field pulling the rotor field. I want to know if the effect of stator field pushing the rotor field is possible.